# Hard / Factory reset iPad 3 without device password and iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipad, restart

I have an iPad 3 which is disabled and not connected to the Internet. It says that I should connect iTunes but then I have to accept the connection. When I press "Next", it says that I have to answer the pop-up on my iPad, which is locked. Also, I've forgotten my security questions. Is there any way to Factory / Hard reset my iPad and then reset my questions?

---

I tried Power + Home but it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reset the iPad by booting into recovering mode.

1. **Turn off** your iPad
2. Connect your iPad to your computer while **holding the Home button**. Keep holding the Home button until you see the recovery-mode screen
3. iTunes will show a display an alert message saying it's detected an iPad in recovery mode.
4. When you see the option to Restore or Update, choose **Restore**. *Keep in mind a factory reset will erase ALL DATA!!*
5. Set up as new iPad

Comment: I followed your instruction, but the iPad just booted straight up into the Lock Screen, no Recover Mode. Also, do I have to turn off iTunes on my computer?

Comment: Keep holding the Home button on reboot. By default iTunes will open automatically when connecting any device.